# Uniq -c based on last two columns in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have below input file , i need to find out now of occurrence last column irrespective of other columns.

I have tried this code but not worked

```
cat filename.txt | sort -t'|' -k3,4 | uniq -c -f1
```

**input** 

09-06-17|19:14:05.862|61284017123|505023892353450
09-06-17|19:29:48.409|61284017123|505023892353457
09-06-17|19:30:05.648|61284017123|505023892353457
09-06-17|19:44:46.085|61284017123|505023892353457
09-06-17|04:23:03.038|61284017941|505023892353450
09-06-17|04:30:50.691|61284017942|505023892353451
09-06-17|04:43:48.407|61284017942|505023892353451
09-06-17|04:27:50.293|61284017944|505023892353453
09-06-17|03:51:24.130|61284017949|505023892353458
09-06-17|04:06:45.220|61284017949|505023892353458


**Output Expected** 
No of occurrence  and any one of line

09-06-17|19:14:05.862|61284017123|505023892353450|2
09-06-17|19:29:48.409|61284017123|505023892353457|3
09-06-17|04:30:50.691|61284017942|505023892353451|2
09-06-17|04:27:50.293|61284017944|505023892353453|1
09-06-17|03:51:24.130|61284017949|505023892353458|2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me :) 
  `awk -F'|' '!z[$4]++{ a[$4]=$0; } END {for (i in a) print a[i]"|" z[i]}'  filename`

Comment: You're sorting before awk then doing something in awk that doesn't require sorted input and then outputting from awk in random order (due to `in`). Makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-u for unique

cat filename.txt | sort -t'|' -k3,4 -u
```

Answer (score 1):

This two-parse solution works here, i.e. first count occurrences and then  print unique lines with the counts:

*parse.awk*

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" }

FNR==NR { 
  h[$NF]++
  next
}

$NF in h { 
  print $0 OFS h[$NF]
  delete h[$NF]
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk input{,}
```

Output:

```
09-06-17|19:14:05.862|61284017123|505023892353450|2
09-06-17|19:29:48.409|61284017123|505023892353457|3
09-06-17|04:30:50.691|61284017942|505023892353451|2
09-06-17|04:27:50.293|61284017944|505023892353453|1
09-06-17|03:51:24.130|61284017949|505023892353458|2
```